# detect which program is creating a file

Tags: macos

Title says it all - I'm on Mac OS X, and I want to detect what program is creating this annoying `awefawef2log` file in my home directory every couple of hours.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic for StackOverflow. The [help] has more information about the types of questions that belong here. Your question is a better fit for [su], which is for general computer, software, and operating system questions. Voting to move there. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite I'd like to do this using DTrace, the programming tool for writing kernel profilers / debuggers. Hence the "dtrace" tag.

Comment: Ok. :-) I'd change my close vote then to "Off topic" because it doesn't show any effort to solve (or even research) this problem yourself. "I want to detect" should be followed by "Here's what I've tried so far to do so, but here's what happened." Unfortunately, I don't have an option of changing the reason for the close vote after it's been cast; the only option is to remove it completely and not be able to vote to close at all. I'll leave it to other readers to use the "off-topic" reason. If you [edit] the question to provide the attempts you've made, I'll gladly retract the vote.

Comment: Probably [`fs_usage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) is the better tool for this than DTrace. `fs_usage -w -f pathname | grep awefawef2log`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your exact question because it's not necessarily an error to try to create a file that already exists.  That said, I think you could solve your immediate problem with

```
bash-3.2# cat who.d 
#include <fcntl.h>

syscall::open:entry
/arg1 & O_CREAT/
{
    /* arg0 might not be paged-in yet */
    self->pathp = arg0;
}

syscall::open:return
/self->pathp && basename(copyinstr(self->pathp)) == $$1/
{
    printf("%s opened %s\n", execname, copyinstr(self->pathp));
    /* free the thread-local storage */
    self->pathp = NULL;
}
bash-3.2# dtrace -Cqs who.d testFile
touch opened testFile
^C

bash-3.2#
```

No doubt there are some edge cases that this will miss, e.g. a file that was opened and then renamed.

If it's important to find only the first `open()` then you could experiment with the fbt provider to look for a function call that's present only if the target file does not already exist.  Typically this would be an inode (but not a vnode) allocation.  However, I think it would be hard work to write something robust and, of course, it wouldn't be stable with respect to OS changes.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use opensnoop:

```
sudo opensnoop -f /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check if file is opened by some application

> $ lsof | grep awefawef2log

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned - whatever program creates it is not currently running.